# How to find all the timestamp values interval by each minute between the two timestamp records

Tags: sql-server, sql-timestamp

I have a table having three fields Id (Integer) - Unique, Open Date (Datetime), Close Date(DateTime):

```
Id  Open Date                  Close Date
1   2019-07-03 16:28:39.497    2019-07-04 16:28:39.497
2   2019-07-04 15:28:39.497    2019-07-05 19:28:39.497
…..N
```

I want to calculate the all the timestamps between open date and close date with an interval of each minute.

So the final output I want is like this:

```
Id  Open Date             Close Date                   TimeStamp Range
1   2019-07-03 16:28:39.497   2019-07-04 16:28:39.497   2019-07-03 16:29:00.0000
1   2019-07-03 16:28:39.497   2019-07-04 16:28:39.497   2019-07-03 16:30:00.0000
1   2019-07-03 16:28:39.497   2019-07-04 16:28:39.497   2019-07-03 16:31:00.0000
1   2019-07-03 16:28:39.497   2019-07-04 16:28:39.497   …..........................
1   2019-07-03 16:28:39.497   2019-07-04 16:28:39.497   2019-07-04 16:27:00.0000
2   2019-07-04 15:28:39.497   2019-07-05 19:28:39.497   2019-07-04 15:29:00.0000
2   2019-07-04 15:28:39.497   2019-07-05 19:28:39.497   2019-07-04 15:30:00.0000
2   2019-07-04 15:28:39.497   2019-07-05 19:28:39.497   2019-07-04 15:31:00.0000
2   2019-07-04 15:28:39.497   2019-07-05 19:28:39.497   ….................................
2   2019-07-04 15:28:39.497   2019-07-05 19:28:39.497   2019-07-05 19:27:00.0000
N   …............................   …...........................    …......................................
```

Would someone write the SQL query for this?

Comment: Hint: Lookup recursive CTEs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all the timestamp values interval by each minute between the two timestamp records in my sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649155/how-to-find-all-the-timestamp-values-interval-by-each-minute-between-the-two-tim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using an ad-hoc tally/numbers table and a `Cross Apply`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] int,[Open Date] datetime,[Close Date] datetime)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'2019-07-03 16:28:39.497','2019-07-04 16:28:39.497')
,(2,'2019-07-04 15:28:39.497','2019-07-05 19:28:39.497')

Select A.*
      ,TSRange = DateAdd(Minute,N,convert(varchar(16),[Open Date],20))
  From @YourTable A
  Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(MINUTE,[Open Date],[Close Date])-1) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                  From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
              )  B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: It Worked. Thanks a lot John :)

Comment: @GirishGandhi Happy to help

Comment: Hey John , Need one more help dear. Can we have the above TSRange Coulmn Field Week Day wise ?

Comment: Need Ts Range date field to show each date by weekday not by each minute. Is it Possible? Please help me to write the query as i am not aware how to use cross apply in sql

Comment: @GirishGandhi not in my office yet. But in the meantime..   change DateDiff(MINUTE,..  to DateDiff (DAY,...       This is done in two places.

Comment: Hey John,  can this code be supported for my sql also?